# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void show() from the type Child2

Tags: apex, inheritance

> Line: 2, Column: 3 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void show() from the type Child2.

Above is the error im getting. How can I rectify it?

```
public Virtual class Parent2 {
public string name;
    public string branch;
    public virtual void show(){
        name='kiran';
        branch='vijayawada';
    }
    public void invoke(){
        system.debug('Name:'+name);
        system.debug('Branch:'+branch);
    }

}
public class Child2 Extends parent2 {
    public integer age;
    public String phone;
    public override Void Show(){
        name='ravi';
        age=90;
        branch='mpl';
        phone='1111';
    }
    public void Display(){
       system.debug('Name:'+name);
       system.debug('Age:'+age);
       system.debug('Branch:'+branch);
       system.debug('Phone:'+phone);
    }
}
```

> Execute:

```
Child2 c=new Child2();
C.show();
C.display();
```

Comment: your code is perfectly running at my DE

Comment: What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more details as where/when are you receiving this error? Is it compile time, runtime, in a test class?

Comment: It is in  compile time Execute Anonymous error

Comment: It's working at my end...just executed my developer console....only difference I can see your method name is started with cap S...and your calling with lower s...but case-sensitivity should not be problem in apex.... Are your running your code in Dev Console?

Comment: ya iam running in developer console

Comment: Do you need **Parent2** to be virtual? Running in Execute Anonymous via dev console with an _abstract_ Parent2 class, I was able to compile and run without exception. I think the issue may have to do with the context in which Execute Anonymous runs, i.e. classes defined therein are considered inner classes of an unseen context.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is due to our use of the **Virtual** keyword in the Parent2 definition. According to the documentation, [classes defined in Execute Anonymous are considered virtual by default](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_anonymous_block.htm).

Be removing the virtual keyword from the class definition, I was able to get this to compile and run as expected in my environment.

```
public class Parent2 {
public string name;
    public string branch;
    public virtual void show(){
        name='kiran';
        branch='vijayawada';
    }
    public void invoke(){
        system.debug('Name:'+name);
        system.debug('Branch:'+branch);
    }

}
public class Child2 Extends parent2 {
    public integer age;
    public String phone;
    public override Void Show(){
        name='ravi';
        age=90;
        branch='mpl';
        phone='1111';
    }
    public void Display(){
       system.debug('Name:'+name);
       system.debug('Age:'+age);
       system.debug('Branch:'+branch);
       system.debug('Phone:'+phone);
    }
}

Child2 c=new Child2();
C.show();
C.display();
```